# Present Facebook likes (shares) in one page

Tags: .net, facebook, model-view-controller, google-plus

My site includes a search results page in which basic information about searched places (say hotels) is shown:

- *Place 1:*
- Address YYY
- Availabilty 3
- Price: 999$

---

- *Place 2:*
- Address YXV
- Availabilty 1
- Price: 99$

etc.

Clicking on a place renders a detailed info page.
Within the detailed info page there are Facebook Like and G+ buttons that users click on (and the info about how many likes the place got so far is also shown).

My question is:
Can I show (only show and not allow clicks) the number of likes from the detailed info page in the search page for each respective place.

The wanted result is:

- *Place 1:*
- **667 Likes, 23 G+** <-this info from Place 1 detailed info page
- Address YYY
- Availabilty 3
- Price: 999$

---

- *Place 2:*
- **777 Likes, 44 G+** <-this info from Place 2 detailed info page
- Address YXV
- Availabilty 1
- Price: 99$

I developed in VS, .NET MVC.

I'd appreciate a detailed answer.

Thnx.

Comment: Since this doesn’t look (at least to me) like you did any proper research on your own before asking, I suggest you start with something like https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+api+how+to+get+number+of+page+likes

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately, I was not able to find a complete answer for my specific problem although I did research beforehand. An "answer" like yours did not help and I guess it deterred others from commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a complete answer for my EXACT problem (working in MVC) so I am posting my solution which works great by the way.

The View renders outer divs, one for each place containing some data. Each dive is actually a form. I place the input and counter div inside the outer one:

```
<div>
  <input class="likes1" type="hidden" id="institueId" value="SpecificPlaceUrl" data-link="" />
  <div class="likes2" id=@resultsId>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then this function countFacebookLikes, which should be preferably deferred till the page fully loads, loops through the divs

```
function countFacebookLikes() {
    $('.likes2').each(function () {
        var $currentForm = $(this).closest('.enterFormClass');
        var token = 'yyyyyyyyyyy|xxxxxxxxxxxx',
            resultsId = $('.likes1',$currentForm).val(),
            urlName = resultsId;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { access_token: token, id: urlName },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data !=undefined && data.share != undefined)
                {
                    $('#results' + resultsId).html('<span class="YourRelevantClasses" style="YourRelevantStyles">' + data.share.share_count + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up">' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<i class="fa fa-facebook-square" >' + '</span>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

1) One can change Facebook data param to whatever he/she wants to count - total, shares etc.

2) For multiple urls there are q&a in stackoverflow and elsewhere that use https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=url1,url2 etc. this may be useful for some but for me it wasn't working due to the large number of urls and the work for reconstructing specific url strings each time.